# Get value of select on change with class name

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to add select in each row of a table.
The selects are assigned a class name.

Now, I need to get the value of the select on change using this dynamically assigned class name.

```
$select = $('<select class="medName"></select>');

for(var i = 0;i < tmp.length-1; i++){
                $option = $('<option>'+tmp[i]+'</option>');
                $select.append($option);
}
```

Here tmp contains data fetched from backend.

Finally,

```
    var $row = $('<tr></tr>');
    var $data1 = $('<td></td>');
    var $data2 = $('<td></td>');
    var $data3 = $('<td></td>');
    var $data4 = $('<td></td>');

    //alert($select.html());

    $data1.append($select);
    $data2.append($type);
    $data3.append($text);
    $data4.append($label);

    $row.append($data1);
    $row.append($data2);
    $row.append($data3);
    $row.append($data4);

    $row.insertAfter('#CashMemoBody');
```

This works perfectly fine.

Now when I do,

```
$('.medName').on('change', function (e) {
        var val = $(this).find('option :selected').html();
        alert(val);
});
```

I do not even get an alert.

Inspect Element shows, that the classes are properly assigned.

Whats going wrong ?

Here the problem is NOT only dynamic binding, but also getting the value of the selected option. None of the provided solutions seem to work here. Hence the question.

Comment: `var val = $('option :selected',this).html()`

Comment: `$('.medName').on('change', function (e) {` should be `$('body').on('change', '.medName', function (e) {`

Comment: instead of html can you use val() and check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be-

```
$(document).on('change','.medName',function(){
  var val = $('option:selected',this).val()
  alert(val);
});
```

Because `.medName` is dynamically created

Comment: I get an alert now, but not the content of the option. Something is still off!

Comment: you can use `$(this).val()` to get the selected value

Comment: @AnkitaSingh, What exactly you want? the text or the val attribute of option? Also I have edited my answer for selected value